# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Axis2 Can't find Spring's ApplicationContext with in .aar file

Tags: spring, apache-axis

I am using Axis2, Spring and Hibernate. I created `.aar file` using the following command.

```
jar cvf someName.aar *
```

My `.aar` file looks as below:

```
 _ classFilesWithInPackage (E.g. com/test/.../fileName.java)  
|_ META-INF/(MANIFEST.MF and services.xml)  
|_ applicationContext.xml  
|_ lib/required jars
```

And my `services.xml` is

```
<serviceGroup>
    <service name="SpringInitializationService" class="com.test.service.SpringInitService">
        <description>
            This web service initializes Spring.
        </description>
        <parameter name="ServiceClass">com.test.service.SpringInitService
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="ServiceTCCL">composite</parameter>
        <parameter name="load-on-startup">true</parameter>
    </service>
    <service name="TestService">
        <Description>
            Policy Web Service
        </Description>
        <messageReceivers>
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
                class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
                class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />
        </messageReceivers>
        <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.test.service.TestService
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="ServiceObjectSupplier">
            org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringAppContextAwareObjectSupplier
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="SpringBeanName">axis2SpringIntegrationService</parameter>
        <parameter name="SpringContextLocation">applicationContext.xml</parameter>
    </service>
</serviceGroup>
```

I have implemented the interface `ServiceLifeCycle` and override the following methods as well. Reference site http://fazlansabar.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/apache-axis2-tutorial-integrating-with.html.

```
public class SpringInitService implements ServiceLifeCycle {

    ClassLoader classLoader = null;
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appCtx = null;

    @Override
    public void shutDown(ConfigurationContext configContext, AxisService axisService) {
        appCtx = null;
        classLoader = null;     
    }

    @Override
    public void startUp(ConfigurationContext configContext, AxisService axisService) {

        System.out.println("Inside Spring Init");

        try {
            classLoader = axisService.getClassLoader();
            appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"classpath:**applicationContext.xml"}, false);
            appCtx.setClassLoader(classLoader);
            appCtx.refresh();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        System.out.println("Out of Spring Init");
    }

}
```

When I create .aar file out of it and deploy in `WSO2 server`, it deployed successfully and `com.test.service.SpringInitService` class also initialized at start up without error since I have implemented `ServiceLifeCycle` interface. But When I invoke any service available in `TestService` (2nd service in services.xml) I ended up in error.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Axis2 Can't find Spring's ApplicationContext
```

Someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Also clarify,

```
Whether my .aar folder structure is right?
Can we have more than one service in services.xml as above?
What is the best way to have Axis2, Spring and Hibernate together?
```

**Update:**
   I tried following the below reference from Axis2 site, but has no luck in getting it worked.
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html

Any help is Appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in the spring initialization service in the services.xml:

```
<parameter name="ServiceObjectSupplier"
locked="false">org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringServletContextObjectSupplier</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just put the following code in your applicationContext.xml file.

```
 <bean id="applicationContext" class="org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.ApplicationContextHolder" />
```

Spring will assign applicationContext to ApplicationContextHolder automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own **ApplicationContextHolder**

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext appCtx;

    public ApplicationContextHolder() {}

    /** Spring supplied interface method for injecting app context. */
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
        appCtx = applicationContext;
    }

    /** Access to spring wired beans. */
    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return appCtx;
    }

}
```

Use it in **settings.xml**

```
<bean id="applicationContext"
class="org.ravinda.service.spring.ApplicationContextHolder" />
```